# Full page width box and icon to highlight paragraph

Tags: tcolorbox, adjustbox, fbox

How can a box (like fbox or adjustbox) be stretched to the full page width to highlight a specific paragraph in the text? The definition should work without hardcoding geometry margins that were defined elsewhere. And like in longfbox or tcolorbox, the frame should continue on the next page for longer paragraphs without running through the header and footer. Bonus: an icon (image or text) in the margin would be nice to indicate the purpose of the box.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{widebox}[1][]{%
    enhanced, breakable, spread sidewards, left*=0pt, right*=0pt, boxrule=0pt, colback=cyan!10, #1}
    
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{widebox}
\lipsum[1]
\end{widebox}
\begin{widebox}[colback=red!20,overlay unbroken and first={\node[anchor=west] at ([xshift=1cm]frame.west) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}};}]
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{widebox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To vertically align the image at the top left corner of the panel, I changed the coordinates to: `([xshift=8mm, yshift=-8mm]frame.north west)`.